# Several questions to AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am new to AchartEngine. I am using AchartEngine with android to create a Barchart. I have looked at the aChartEngine API and have created a  Barchart, its working fine.

1. When I want to see my actual view I have to decrease the zoom rate by clicking zoom button which is in right bottom. I need to show a compleate Barchart what I exactly declared in my program with out using zoom button.
2. I need to navigate from one view to another. So, I created one graphical view with ontouchlistner, but it shows error.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Am I missing something here?

```
public class GraphicViewExample extends Activity {
  private String[] mMonth = new String[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
            "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
    int[] x = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int[] income = { 2000, 2500, 2700, 3000, 2800, 3500, 3700, 3800 };
    public static final String TYPE = "type";
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = getDemoDataset();
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = getDemoRenderer();
    private GraphicalView mChartView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.graphicviewexample);
        if (mChartView == null) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, mDataset,
                    mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
            mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
            layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        } else {
            mChartView.repaint();
        }

        mChartView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                /*SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView
                        .getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();*/
                SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
                mRenderer.removeAllRenderers();
                r.setColor(Color.RED);
                mChartView.repaint();
                return true;
            }
        });

        /*mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 * LinearLayout slayout = (LinearLayout)
                 * findViewById(R.id.chart); ChartView =
                 * ChartFactory.getBarChartView( getApplicationContext(),
                 * sDataset, smRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
                 * slayout.addView(ChartView, new LayoutParams(
                 * LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                 * 
                 * ChartView.repaint();

                mChartView.repaint();
            }
        });*/
    }

    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset() {

        XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Income");
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            incomeSeries.add(i, income[i]);
        }

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
        return dataset;

    }

    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getDemoRenderer() {
        XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(130, 130, 230));
        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.3f);
        multiRenderer.setBarWidth(30);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Income Chart");
        multiRenderer.setXTitle("Year 2013");
        multiRenderer.setYTitle("Amount in Dollars");
        //multiRenderer.setZoomLimits(1.0,0.7,1.0,3000.0);
        multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        //multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
        //multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
        multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(7);
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(4000);
        multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        multiRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);
        }

        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
        return multiRenderer;
    }

}
```

Logs:
                 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)

at org.achartengine.renderer.DefaultRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(DefaultRenderer.java:189)

at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:240)

at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:168)

Comment: try multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true); and GraphicalView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) { //your code}}

Comment: I used multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(true) but it doe not works when i touch the view i get errors i have edited the logcat.

Comment: I found the answer finally, after removing all renderers i have to add SimpleSeriesRenderer object to mRenderer

Comment: I got the solution. If i need to display the whole chart to be visible, i need to pass min and max values to x and y coordinates here my x index starts from 0 to 7 so i have to pass Xmin(-1) and Xmax(8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for my line graph,

```
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    SeriesSelection seriesSelection = ((GraphicalView) v)
                            .getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

                    Log.d("sreedhu", String.valueOf(seriesSelection));
                    if (seriesSelection == null) {
                        Log.d("sreedhu", "Nothing Selected");

                    } else {
//your code}
}
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. It works better when compare to OnTouchListener because, if i use OnClick instead of OnTouch i can resize my chart by using zoom button but i need to fix default zoomrate which is to visible compleate Bar chart.

Comment: ty for sharing this, I have been looking for this. =)

Answer (score 0):

use this codes to zoom your barchart...!

```
renderer.setScale((float) 1);
```

Comment: I got the solution 

If i need to display the whole chart to be visible, i need to pass min and max values to x and y coordinates
here my x index starts from 0 to 7 so i have to pass Xmin(-1) and Xmax(8).

Comment: Is it so hard to write 1.0f?